# Strongloop loopback how to assign static roles to new users

Tags: angularjs, authorization, roles, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have cloned a `https://github.com/beeman/loopback-angular-admin` 
and I have created a couple of new roles using the loopback explorer but how do I assign roles to users that I create

I have a user model which extends from User model in loopback 
and the model file is like this -

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "plural": "users",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "accessTokens": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "accessToken",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    },
    "identities": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "userIdentity",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    },
    "credentials": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "userCredential",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    },
    "roles": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Role",
      "foreignKey": "principalId",
      "through": "RoleMapping"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

and my user.js is like -

```
module.exports = function (user) {

  // Set the username to the users email address by default.
  user.observe('before save', function setDefaultUsername(ctx, next) {
    if (ctx.instance) {
      if(ctx.isNewInstance) {
        ctx.instance.username = ctx.instance.email;
      }
      ctx.instance.status = 'created';
      ctx.instance.created = Date.now();
    }
    next();
  });

};
```

Now, I want to assign roles and principals to users based on a property `ctx.instance.type` that I am passing from client

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you already have a finite set of Roles created in your Role table, use an after save hook to assign the just-created User a specific Role:

```
User.observe('after save', function setRoleMapping(ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.instance) {
    if(ctx.isNewInstance) {

      var RoleMapping = User.app.models.RoleMapping;
      // var roleId = based on type lookup or static?

      RoleMapping.create({
        principalType: "USER",
        principalId: ctx.instance.id,
        roleId: roleId
      }, function(err, roleMapping) {
        if (err) {return console.log(err);}

        // success stuff

      }):

    }
  }
  next();
});
```

Code not tested, just a general idea. You can't use a before save hook since you won't know the ID of the User to use for the principalId in the RoleMapping table.

**UPDATE**: Version including looking up the Role by type passed in:

```
user.observe('after save', function setRoleMapping(ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.instance) {
    if(ctx.isNewInstance) {

      // look up role based on type
      //
      Role.find({where: {name: ctx.instance.type}}, function(err, role) {
        if (err) {return console.log(err);}

        RoleMapping.create({
          principalType: "USER",
          principalId: ctx.instance.id,
          roleId: role.id
        }, function(err, roleMapping) {

          if (err) {return console.log(err);}

          console.log('User assigned RoleID ' + role.id + ' (' + ctx.instance.type + ')');

        }):

      });

    }
  }
  next();
});
```

Query docs are here: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Querying+data

Comment: so how do I get the roleId by querying database model based on the `ctx.instance.type` value

Comment: It depends on how you are determining the role from the type value. How many roles are there? Is the role name just the type name?

Comment: Yes it is just the type name, and there are around 6 roles other than admin but just for learning how to query the roles or any model I wanted to know how can I do this by querying the database first and then attaching the roleId from the found role

Comment: Added a version with Role lookup to my answer. But be careful here, if the type passed in isn't in the list, you won't have a `role.id` to make a RoleMapping entry, so you'll need to add logic to handle bad type values. Using observers also has the added complexity of needing to continue with `next()`, and you can also pass errors `next(err)` so they bubble up (but you'll have to put in multiple `next(err)`s inside each callback context, or use promises with a single `catch()`.